# Problems with Word Add-in After MS Office Update to version 13628.20274

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

I have problems with my Word Add-in. It doen't work.
After some investigation I figured out that this issue apears after Office update.
I mean in elder versions of MS Word was used Internet Explorer. But after update the engine is Microsoft Edge Legacy. Also I now that now exists new Microsoft Edge based on Chromium.

So the question is next, is there a way to make my MS Word use Microsoft Edge based on Chromium instead of Microsoft Edge Legacy?

In addition:
in my research I depends on data from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins
Also tried to install WebView2 but it doen't help.
Current Version of MD Office: 13628.20274
Current Version of Word: 16.0.13628.20234

Will be grateful for any information related to my issue.
Thank in advance and have a nice day))

[image]

Comment: Office decides what browser to use based on the versions in the article that you linked to. You can't force it. If you are on Windows 10 and you have installed WebView2, then Office should be using Edge (Chromium). What makes you think that it is not?

Comment: Thank you for answer)
I installed WebView2 from this site: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/ . But after restarting MS word in security info of my Add-in still was mentioned Microsoft Edge Legacy. And my Add-in doen't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "security info of my Add-in still was mentioned Microsoft Edge Legacy"? Where do you see this information.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the info the screen that I just added)

Comment: The Security Info box says that SSL is turned off. You should be using HTTPS. See if that fixes the problem. If not, we'll try something else.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use HTTPS for my Add-in due to some restrictions that I have.

Comment: Please use HTTPS for developing so we can see if that fixes the problem with Edge Legacy.

Comment: @RickKirkham it doesn't fix the problem, I have exactly the same problem and I am using SSL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558304/how-to-force-microsoft-office-addin-to-use-edge-webview2-runtime

Comment: @YuraLukashchuk did you happen to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Office installation. [Build 13628.20274](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel#version-2101-january-26) is a release in the Current/Monthly Channel but is from January 2021. With this build the WebView2 control should be included and installed automatically. But, as you are several months behind the usual update schedule, your administrator might have put some restriction in place that prevent normal update installation.

As you installed the WebView2 control manually, you should double check that it is enabled in Office. The registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\Win32WebView2` must exist and must have a value of **`1`** (DWORD).