# How to force Microsoft Office Addin to use Edge Webview2 runtime

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I read this nice [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/understanding-office-add-ins-runtime/) from Microsoft explaining how the Addin runtime works.

I am using **Windows 10 Enterprise** and the system has already **Microsoft Edge WebView2**:

[image]

My Office 365 version is **16.0.13801.20442 32-bit** and hence it is Microsoft 365 ver. >= 16.0.13530.20424, which according to [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) would force the Addin to use Microsoft Edge with WebView2.

[image]

But it is not using it. It is using the legacy EdgeHTML runtime

[image]

### TLDR

If these 2 conditions are met:

- Microsoft 365 ver. >= 16.0.13530.20424
- Edge WebView2 installed

Why the runtime of Addin is the old EdgeHTML?

Comment: Maybe you have to reboot the computer before the installation of WebView2 takes effect. (Also, if you right click the task pane, is there a context menu?)

Comment: @RickKirkham did it today, no success

Comment: @RickKirkham no, when I right-click on the taskpane, nothing happens

Comment: @RickKirkham I rebooted the PC right now to be sure and the problem remains

Comment: I'll see if I can get any help internally. If you don't get an answer in the next day or so, the only things I can suggest are to uninstall and then reinstall WebView2. If that doesn't work. Try uninstalling and then reinstall Office.

Comment: @RickKirkham please do ask help internally, because I can't do anything of that (uninstall and reinstall software) without a huge chain of command of approvals. I need clear solutions to send above the chain of hierarchy. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post may have the answer [Understanding the Office Add-ins runtime](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/understanding-office-add-ins-runtime/). Scroll down to this note:

> Note: Customers on the Semi-Annual Enterprise channel of Office can expect to receive version Version 2102 in July 2021. Admins at these customers will need to take an additional step to enable the use of WebView2. They must create the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\Win32WebView2 and set its value to dword:00000001.

Comment: So, considering that I am already using Office 2012, I just need to ask my admin to create the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\Win32WebView2` and set its value to `dword:00000001`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the registry key as mentioned in the accepted answer did not work for me. Tried every other WebView2 builds. None worked.

What worked was updating windows to the latest build and it automatically started working.
(from Windows 10.0.14393 to 10.0.19041)